# JavaScript Form Validation Function: Looping each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of form input elements on which I want to run a loop. From the result, I need to run a few conditional statements so that I can validate them using their name attributes. I've used jQuery for that and used **.each** method for looping through them. Thus I can add/remove class name to invalid input elements.

It's little difficult to describe in words. But the code block bellow will make sense:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmx36wxe/)

```js
function formValid() {
  var valid = true;

  $('form input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      valid = false;
      $(this).addClass('red-border');
    } else if (true /* if "tel" is not a number */ ) { // <- here I want to validate using input name attribute
      valid = false;
      $(this).addClass('red-border');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('red-border');
    }
  });

  return valid;
}

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (formValid()) {
    alert('Yay!');
  }
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">

  <p>
    <input type="text" name="name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="tel">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="email">
  </p>

  <p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: This looks like working code so what is your question?

Comment: I want to reach name attributes from the loop result and validate each input. Please see the comment on JS code

Comment: Stick this inside your each loop `console.log($(this).attr('name'));`

Comment: no. I meant something like 

`if ( /* $(this) attr name is tel == NaN */ ) { 
    // add error class to $(this);
} `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/t9ayvken/

CSS:

```
.red-border {
  border-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#">

  <p>
    <input class="must-validate" type="text" name="name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="must-validate" type="text" name="tel">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="must-validate" type="text" name="email">
  </p>

  <p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>

</form>
```

JQuery:

```
/*validation functions for each input type*/
function validateName(event){
    var $this = $(this);
  /* validation is done here */
  if(false){
   $this.removeClass('red-border');
  }
  else {
    /* not valid*/  
    $this.addClass('red-border');
  }
}
function validateTel(event){

}
function validateEmail(event){

}

/*add validation event handlers*/
$(document).on('validate','[name="name"]',validateName);
$(document).on('validate','[name="tel"]',validateTel);
$(document).on('validate','[name="email"]',validateEmail);


function formValid() {
    var valid = true;

  /*Trigger validation events for all required inputs*/
  $('input.must-validate').trigger('validate');


 /* After validation is complete check to see if any are invalid */      
  if( $('input.must-validate.red-border').length ){
    alert('the form is invalid');
    valid = false;
  } 

  return false;
  //return valid;
}

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

  if ( formValid() ) {
    alert('Yay!');
  }
});
```

Comment: I may have more [name="email"] attribute in the same document assigned to other forms.  `$(document).on('validate','[name="name"]',validateName);` won't it be a reason for any conflict?

Comment: @AnwarHussain just change your trigger code to only look for input's in the current form.

Comment: The .on( 'validate' ) is triggering an infinite loop once I actually try to submit the form inside the if( formValid ) success block.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest returning a list of errors instead of a boolean flag.

```js
function formValid() {
  var errorMsgs = [];

  $('form input').each(function() {
    var msg = [],
        val = $(this).val();
    
    // Check blanks
    if (val == '') 
      msg.push( `${$(this).attr('name')} is blank`);
    
    // Check numbers
    if ($(this).attr('name') === 'tel' && isNaN(val))
      msg.push( `${$(this).attr('name')} is not a number`);
    
    // Handle results
    if (msg.length > 0){
      errorMsgs.push(...msg);
      $(this).addClass('red-border');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('red-border');
    }
  });

  return errorMsgs;
}
$('button').on('click', function(event) {

  var errors = formValid();
  if (errors.length === 0) {
    alert('Yay!');
  } else {
    alert(errors.join('\r'));
  }
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">

  <p>
    <input type="text" name="name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="tel">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="email">
  </p>

  <p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: Probably I could not make my question clear to you. I want something like this: `if ( /* $(this) attr name is tel == NaN */ ) { /* add error class to $(this); */ }` May be I can add another condition inside too.